# Junit fail following tutorial MongoDB, Springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, junit

I am following this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb

Only dot 1,2,3

I need insert and check new registers in my mongoDB embebed.

this is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

It is my test.java:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.DataMongoTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import com.batch.DesarrolloBatch.model.Documento;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

@DataMongoTest
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {


            @Test
            public void test(@Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
                // given
                DBObject objectToSave = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                    .add("_id", "999999999999")
                    .get();

                // when
                mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

                List<Documento> list =  mongoTemplate.findAll(Documento.class, "collection");

               System.out.println("size " + list.size());

                // then
                assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(Documento.class, "collection")).extracting("_id")
                    .containsOnly("999999999999");
            }
}
```

I am trying insert a new Documento with attribute _id value= 99999999

But this code failed, so, I am trying see the size my List for know if I insert success...

I get this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Method test should have no parameters
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:208)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

I am new in Junit, mongodb ... I only want use mongoDB embebed and insert and check my bbdd .... thanks...

Comment: Shouldn't `mongoTemplate` be a field of the class instead of a method parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an annotation on the class level: @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {

        @Test
        public void test(@Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
            // your test code
        } 
}
```

**Please read the tutorial carefully.**

Here is the link to the GitHub Repo where you can find the pom.xml and all the source code as well:

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/persistence-modules/spring-boot-persistence-mongodb

Comment: Should be using `RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` for Junit4, With Junit5 the ExtendWith isn't required if you're on a late enough version.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/mongo/DataMongoTest.html

Comment: Please follow the tutorial! That's how the pom.xml must look like: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/spring-boot-persistence-mongodb/pom.xml

Comment: Darren, with RunWith(SpringRunner.class) I get 3 erros: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknow source),,,,, at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49),,,,,,, atorg.springframework.test.context.junit.4.SpringUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:137)